# Change the title to ViewControllers using the storyboard and tab controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I have a question about UINavigationController.

I have create a project with storyboard using skd 7.

In my storyboard I have add a first NavigationViewController cnnected to TabBar Controller.
Now, into every ViewController of my TabBar I would to set the title...

In a first time I have try to set the title using:

```
[self setTitle:@"my title"];
```

But I can't to see the title..So, I have try with this (int a ViewDidLoad method).

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"My title";
```

In this way I can see my correct title..but I can not figure out ...why?. What is the best way or the correct way to assign the title to my controller dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is this `self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"My title";` because you in order to change a title for a view that is pushed via UINavigationController you have to inform the navigation controller to do so.

Without the navigation controller, the other would be the correct answer. The issue here is that even without the navigation controller the first view in the nav controller should get UITabBarItem title.